# convertir codigo de ejs a jade

Tags: jade, ejs

tengo el siguiente codigo hecho en ejs

```
<div class="container">
        <h1>Students</h1>

        <ul class="list-group">
            <% students.forEach( function( student ) { %>
                <li class="list-group-item"><%= student.name %></li>
            <% }) %>
        </ul>

        <% if (pageCount > 1) { %>
            <ul class="pagination">
                <% if (currentPage > 1) { %>
                    <li><a href="/?page=1">&laquo;</a></li>
                <% } %>
                <% var i = 1;
                if (currentPage > 5) {
                    i = +currentPage - 4;
                } %>
                <% if (i !== 1) { %>
                    <li class="disabled"><a href="#">...</a></li>
                <% } %>
                <% for (i; i<=pageCount; i++) { %>
                    <% if (currentPage == i) { %>
                        <li class="active"><span><%= i %> <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></span></li>
                    <% } else { %>
                        <li><a href="/?page=<%= i %>"><%= i %></a></li>
                    <% } %>
                    <% if (i == (+currentPage + 4)) { %>
                        <li class="disabled"><a href="#">...</a></li>
                    <% break; } %>
                <% } %>
                <% if (currentPage != pageCount) { %>
                    <li><a href="/?page=<%= pageCount %>">&raquo;</a></li>
                <% } %>
            </ul>
        <% } %>

    </div>
```

mi conversion a jade es:

```
div(class="container")
        h1 Students

        ul(class="list-group")
            each item in students
                li(class="list-group-item") item.name

        if (pageCount > 1) 
            ul(class="pagination")
                if currentPage > 1 
                    li
                      a(href="/?page=1")
                var i = 1;
                if currentPage > 5 
                    i = +currentPage - 4;
                if i !== 1  
                    li(class="disabled")
                        a(href="#") ...
                for (var i; i<=pageCount; i++)  
                    if currentPage == i  
                        li(class="active")
                            span i  
                                span(class="sr-only") (current)
                    else 
                        li
                          a(href="/?page=<%= i %>")
                            = i 
                    if (i == (+currentPage + 4))
                        li(class="disabled")
                            a(href="#") ...
                        break;
                if (currentPage != pageCount)
                    li
                      a(href="/?page=<%= pageCount %>")
```

pero no funciona, los conversores en linea no convierten, ayuda a convertir a codigo JADE.